Platform Resource Loader in LWR sites
I am just trying to understand the technical explanation of why a platform resource loader does not work in LWR sites, what is the workaround to make it work?
We have a few LWCs that use static resources (JS library stored in CDN) and would like to understand the LWR sites to see if it's possible to migrate these LWC to LWR sites.

As I understand it, LWR uses a different security model that's incompatible with lightning-platform-resource-loader. The intended method is to Integrate Third-Party Libraries Using the Privileged Script Tag. Basically, you use an <x-oasis-script> tag instead of the <script> tag, which imports the script and grants it full permission to the DOM, bypassing the Shadow DOM entirely. Note that you must used Relaxed CSP and specify the appropriate host in the allowhost setting.

I understand that there is a change in the security model. But what does this mean for someone trying to use a third-party library like Bootstrap or Font Awesome or something complicated like esri-leaflet in their LWCs?
Do we have to use  <x-oasis-script> tag in the LWC itself?

@DeepDesai That's my understanding, but I haven't had a chance to test it.
